# animation works once when opening a cart drawer and then doesn't work afterwards

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, animation

I've been dealing with this bug for some time and I cannot figure out what to do.

I have two simple CSS animations for opening and closing the cart.

```
.animate-close-cart {
  animation: closeCart 0.2s 0s 1 linear forwards;
}
@keyframes closeCart {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-35%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.animate-open-cart {
  animation: openCart 0.2s 0s 1 linear forwards;
}
@keyframes openCart {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-35%);
  }
}
```

upon clicking my cart button I add or remove the appropriate class:

**Opening the cart:**

```
       value: function _openMiniCart() {
         var mainWrapper = document.getElementById("main_wrapper");
         mainWrapper.classList.remove("animate-close-cart");
         mainWrapper.classList.add("animate-open-cart");
       }
```

**Closing the cart:**

```
       value: function _closeMiniCart() {
         var mainWrapper = document.getElementById("main_wrapper");
         mainWrapper.classList.remove("animate-open-cart");
         mainWrapper.classList.add("animate-close-cart");
       }
```

The `main_wrapper` block is wrapped around my entire webpage:

```
<body>
 <div id="main_wrapper">
   // header, template, page contents etc.
 <div/>
</body>
```

Opening the cart the animation plays, the web page moves to the left showing the cart. Perfect.
Closing the cart the animation plays, the web page moves back to the right, hiding the cart.

Then...

Opening it once again, the webpage just *jumps* without animation to the left, showing the cart,
But closing it, it plays the animation and moves back to the right.

Every open after the first initial open always makes the webpage just immediately jump to `-35%`.

I don't know how to debug this or what could be causing this issue.

edit:

With CSS transform the same bug where it only offers a smooth transition on the first open cart, all other open carts jump immediately:

```
#main_wrapper {
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.animate-close-cart {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.animate-open-cart {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: You don't need `animation` for this simple A-to-B state change. Leverage CSS transitions instead.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen I've edited my question to include CSS transitions- the same bug occurs.

Comment: Just throwing something out there, instead of doing a classList.remove, then classList.add, try just a classList.replace.  That may at least get rid of the jumpyness.

Comment: You should have a default state, like `.cart` with your `translate(-35%)` and a class `.cart-open` with `translate(0)`. That way you only toggle on/off a single class. Additionally, your updated code example has both closed and open to `translate(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

So when you say the entire page moves, do you mean you slide the main content screen a bit out of view? Or you allow the blocks to keep everything visible on both sides if they're both available? I'm not sure I'm understanding the intent correctly but here's an example of an effect I've used in the past if it helps accomplish your goal. Otherwise a reproducible example of your pain points instead of just snippets would likely make it more clear to find you a solution. Cheers.

```js
toggleMe = () => {

  const side = document.getElementById('side-wrapper');
  
  side.classList.toggle('slide-me');

}
```

```css
#main-wrapper {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 2rem;
  border: red 5px dashed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: hidden; /* make this visible if you want to see in action */
}

#section-wrapper, #side-wrapper {
  outline: #fff 3px dashed;
  outline-offset: -10px;
}

#section-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00f;
}

#side-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #0f0;
  margin-right: -350px;
  transition: margin-right 1s ease-in-out;
}

.slide-me {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

#example input:checked:after {
  content: 'SIDE IS OPEN';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<label id="example">
  Click to toggle side slide
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleMe()">
</label>

<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div id="section-wrapper"></div>
  <div id="side-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```